# Sennheiser G3 event audio

Tags: video, audio, wireless

So I work a lot filming events making aftermovies. Often my job requires me to get a master out from the mixer or the sound tech and I am at the will of them so to speak with regards to my audio. Rode Video Mics, Shotguns close to the stage .etc. all provide too much echo/reverb and overall bad audio. When I get master out I rarely have a problem, and usually get pretty good audio.

However, I have noticed that 99% of the in-house audio is transmitted wirelessly via Sennheiser G3's. Usually the receiver is this Sennheiser rack mount device. All in all something like [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/843445-REG/Sennheiser_EW122_135G3_G_EW122_G3_DUAL_LAVALIER_HH.html). My question is, if I get a [G3 receiver](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/618789-REG/Sennheiser_EK_100_G3_A_EK_100_G3_Wireless.html) couldn't I just get the frequency of the transmitter and 'tap' into the speakers transmitters, and secondly, would this cause an issue for the soundbooth guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly done.

I suppose with modern digital systems it might be more complicated, but with standard analog systems it should work fine. You'll just need the frequency from the FOH team.

Comment: And it wouldnt cause any interference with their pickup?

Comment: No, it's just a receiver.

Comment: Is there only one wireless mic in use during the whole event ? Can you check in advance that your receiver will be on the same frequency range that the wireless mic ? What if the wireless gets into trouble and that the sound tech switch to a cabled mic ? Aren't there other sound sources during the event (movies/presentation) ?

Comment: An alternate method is to get a direct out from the board for only that channel, if he's using an analog console, this is usually pretty straightforward.

Comment: @audionuma I don't really care to pick up presentation audio from videos .etc. its just their voices im interested in. Rarely at these types of events you have speakers at a podium, thats why they mic them up with G3's.